# C# - Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: c#, json

I know there's many threads about this but I don't understand this json output. I have managed to deserialize json from this site before but they differ.

My class looks like this:

```
public class Bids
{
    public string bids { get; set; }
    public string asks { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdateId { get; set; }
}
```

Download data:

```
var depth = w.DownloadString("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT&limit=20");
```

Deserialize:

```
var book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bids[]>(depth);
```

"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object"

Data (https://api.binance.com/api/v1/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT&limit=20) looks like this:

```
{"lastUpdateId":192569803,"bids":[["6525.40000000","0.62166200",[]],["6524.40000000","0.04081700",[]],["6524.39000000","2.53414400",[]],["6524.13000000","0.53788600",[]],["6523.84000000","3.00000000",[]]],"asks":[["6527.00000000","1.54106400",[]],["6527.51000000","0.37739500",[]],["6527.53000000","0.31064700",[]],["6528.61000000","0.15400000",[]]]}
```

Comment: the properties don't match `lastUpdateId` is a number, bids is a nested array of strings

Comment: It's just a hunch (I don't know how JSON deserialization works in .NET), but I noticed that each item in `bids` is an array rather than an object. Maybe `DeserializeObject` expects actual JSON objects, rather than arrays whose items incidentally map to the fields in an object?

Comment: As i can see bids is two dimensional array

Comment: @J doe copy your JSON and search for JSON to C# class on Google this will make a c# class for you from JSON structure

Comment: I did that, but how do I loop through and get the data from this? public int lastUpdateId { get; set; }
        public List<List<object>> bids { get; set; }
        public List<List<object>> asks { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

You can get an idea as to what, your class should look like by using something like the excellent [Json2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), you can also use VS paste special 'paste as json..'

Here's how the class should look. dont forget to new up the lists!

```
public class RootObject
{
  public int lastUpdateId { get; set; }
  public List<List<object>> bids { get; set; }
  public List<List<object>> asks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to to this thanks to @prashant-pimpale comment but how do I loop through this array and get the bids and asks?

Comment: May be forEach inside forEach will do

Comment: we would need to see the array, perhaps ask a new question with the array so we can take a look at it

Comment: I would recommended take rootobject and debug the code to get the list of list data

Comment: Actually it says it's not enumerable..? I will start a new thread to not clutter this one.

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to this:

```
 public class RootObject
 {
  public int lastUpdateId { get; set; }
  public List<List<object>> bids { get; set; }
  public List<List<object>> asks { get; set; }
 }
```

And then DeserializeObject but I am not sure how to access `List<List<object>>` data!